# Why tf.keras.layers.concatenate adds parameters to my model?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to convert a Tensorflow code into Pytorch.
My UNet in Pytorch has different number of parameters than Tensorflow's. After many researches, I figured out that the concatenate step in my TF code adds parameters to my model (+3,133,440). Of course, I have some skepticism about that but the summary with and without this layer gives different results for sure...
Could someone take a look ?

Thanks !

#### Tensorflow code

```py
# Encoder Utilities

def conv2d_block(input_tensor, n_filters, nb_conv=2, kernel_size = 3):
  x = input_tensor
  for i in range(nb_conv):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = n_filters, kernel_size = (kernel_size, kernel_size),\
            kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
  
  return x


def encoder_block(inputs, n_filters=64, pool_size=(2,2), dropout=0.3):
  f = conv2d_block(inputs, n_filters=n_filters)
  p = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(f)
  p = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(p)

  return f, p


def encoder(inputs):
  f1, p1 = encoder_block(inputs, n_filters=64, pool_size=(2,2), dropout=0.3)
  f2, p2 = encoder_block(p1, n_filters=128, pool_size=(2,2), dropout=0.3)
  f3, p3 = encoder_block(p2, n_filters=256, pool_size=(2,2), dropout=0.3)
  f4, p4 = encoder_block(p3, n_filters=512, pool_size=(2,2), dropout=0.3)

  return p4, (f1, f2, f3, f4)

def bottleneck(inputs):
  bottle_neck = conv2d_block(inputs, n_filters=1024)
  return bottle_neck

# Decoder Utilities

def decoder_block(inputs, conv_output, nb_conv=2, n_filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=3, dropout=0.3):
  u = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, kernel_size, strides = strides, padding = 'same')(inputs)
  c = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u, conv_output])
  c = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)(c)
  c = conv2d_block(c, n_filters, nb_conv, kernel_size=3)

  return c


def decoder(inputs, convs, output_channels):
  f1, f2, f3, f4 = convs

  c6 = decoder_block(inputs, f4, n_filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), dropout=0.3)
  c7 = decoder_block(c6, f3, n_filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), dropout=0.3)
  c8 = decoder_block(c7, f2, n_filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), dropout=0.3)
  c9 = decoder_block(c8, f1, n_filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), dropout=0.3)

  outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(output_channels, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)

  return outputs


OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 3

def unet():
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128, 128,3))
  encoder_output, convs = encoder(inputs)
  bottle_neck = bottleneck(encoder_output)
  outputs = decoder(bottle_neck, convs, output_channels=OUTPUT_CHANNELS)
  
  # create the model
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

  return model

# instantiate the model
model = unet()

# see the resulting model architecture
model.summary()
```

#### Summary WITH `c = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u, conv_output])`

```
=================================================================
Total params: 34,513,475
Trainable params: 34,513,475
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

#### Summary WITHOUT `c = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u, conv_output])`

```py
def decoder_block(inputs, conv_output, nb_conv=2, n_filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=3, dropout=0.3):
  u = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, kernel_size, strides = strides, padding = 'same')(inputs)
  #>>>> c = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u, conv_output])<<<<
  c = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)(u)
  c = conv2d_block(c, n_filters, nb_conv, kernel_size=3)

  return c
```

```
=================================================================
Total params: 31,380,035
Trainable params: 31,380,035
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: If I read your code correctly than the concatenation happens along channel axis, thereby increasing the number of channels. The convolution that follows it will then have to have more parameters as it has more input channels.

Comment: Oh you are right... I didn't see that the `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` default parameters was "dim = -1"... So it increases the number of channels by adding the two outputs.
Is there an elegant way to do this as a layer in Pytorch ? I didn't find any torch.nn class nor torch.nn.functional class to do this...

Comment: Sorry, I also only know `torch.cat()` ... You could create a custom `torch.nn.Module`, though, would just be a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explications about the resolution of my problem, thanks to @Jan.

- In the UNet architecture, the skip connection part works differently as the ResNet one. The UNet needs to **concatenate** the outputs of the encoder part layers with the decoder layers ones, whereas the ResNet **adds** them. This mean the number of channel will increase in each decoding step.
- Also, Pytorch doesn't seem to provide any `torch.nn` function that concatenate tensors *as a layer*. The use of the `torch.cat` seems to be the only way to do this.
- The `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` uses `axis=-1` as default parameters while `torch.cat` uses `dim=0`.
- Finally, since inputs in Pytorch are usually in (B,C,H,W) one should use `dim=1` as the `torch.cat` parameter (to concat C channels). Whereas in Tensorflow, inputs are (B,H,W,C) so one should use the default parameter `axis=-1` for the `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` function.

Tensorflow provides a